# MS SQL Server 2008 R2 Import Export Wizard: Calling another DB for generating SSIS package

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm attempting to modify an existing SSIS package generated by the Import/Export Wizard (64-bit) by restamping the query into the package. It calls a database on the same LAN as the calling SQL Server, but is run from a 2nd SQL server, so that the package can be called on demand for loading data from a stored procedure as part of a server job on the calling server.

Config works like this:
On server where platform data resides (MS SQL Server 2008 R2)

1. Database table has subset of fields from our platform, loaded and defined in the designer.
2. There exists a view, which calls the table and imports its data to the view
3. Stored Procedure is a complicated union query with a bunch of left outer joins.

On calling server (MS SQL Server 2008 R2)

1. Import Export wizard is used to generate SSIS package which sql server job can call on demand and periodically to load the data into the appropriate table and thus, load the view.
2. SQL Server job configured to use the package created/modified to load said data.

SSIS package does this (from calling server):

1. Source data: dbservername, SQL server authentication
2. Destination data: dbservername (same as above), SQL server authentication
3. Query: Execute _NameOfMyStoredProcedure
   Note: existing package is encrypted.

When it gets to this point, it sometimes, but does not always timeout, and has not in the past, until now. The change is the addition of some columns to the SP's query that loads the data.

My Question: is there a way [ reg entry, setting value on the database, etc ] to modify the timeout value [ appears to be either 15 or 30 sec ] so that the Import/Export wizard will allow the parsing of the query so that the SSIS package can be parsed?

or alternately,

Is there a way to modify the query in design of the SSIS package without going through the import/export wizard? Note: the calling server does not have the BI studio installed.

Comment: BI Studio just needs to be installed on one of the SQL Servers. You edit the package there then you can run it on any SQL Server with the SSIS runtime installed (basically if it has DTExec.exe). I suggest you learn to edit the package in BIDS.

Comment: Nick, thank you, closing up an old thread. BIDS works brilliantly for this purpose and it's saved a ton of time. Quick note for future readers: BIDS need not be on the server itself to modify the SSIS package, just somewhere that can read the file system on the sql server. Local to the server? yup, or local to the network and the drive is accessible by admin share? yup.

Comment: True - it doesn't need to be installed in the server.